# How to display an array object using useState hooks

Tags: reactjs

/*I want to display in row and column the array element which is inside the useState hook. I use to do it in different way while creating a component only that store the array then create another component which will read it... but i want to do it in one component where useState store the array and display it in the render function*/

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import{Col,Row,Container} from 'react-bootstrap';

function Product() {
    const [product, setProduct] = useState([
        {img:'pexels-charles-kettor-1005162.jpg' , price:'500$', id: 1},
        {img:'pexels-mike-b-1104768.jpg', price:'320$', id:2},
        {img:"pexels-zsolt-joo-2882234.jpg", price:"555$", id:3},
        {img:"pexels-pixabay-326259.jpg", price:"365$", id:4},
        {img:"pexels-pixabay-164634.jpg", price:"545$", id:5},
        {img:"pexels-trace-constant-707046.jpg", price:"200$", id:6},
        {img:"pexels-mike-b-116675.jpg", price:"988$", id:7},
        {img:"pexels-mike-b-170811.jpg", price:"100$", id:8},
    ])
  return (
    <div>
        <Container>
            <Row>
              {product.map()}          
            </Row>
        </Container>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Product
```

// here is what i used to do create variable that store the array
[image]

// then create a component that will map the variable
[image]

Comment: Here is an example I made for someone awhile back. Instead of just using the item you will need to access the objects properties and pass those in. https://codesandbox.io/s/usestate-array-qgdx3o

Comment: [Please post text, not images.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: You already have the code, what is the problem?